# scipy.integrate.solve_ivp: Why doesn't the number of Jacobian evaluations equal the number of function evaluations?

Tags: python, scipy, ode, integrator

[image: Number of Jacobian Evaluations doesn't equal number of function evaluations]

Why is it that when I run scipy.integrate.solve_ivp with the Radau method, the number of Jacobian evaluations doesn't equal the number of function evaluations? Specifically, in my code, it only evaluates the Jacobian once or twice, even though the Jacobian changes at every step.

Answer (score 0):

Jacobian evaluation and factoring is an expensive operation. For the correct and efficient working of the ODE integrator an approximate Jacobian is sufficient. The solver algorithms a once computed Jacobian for as long as possible before renewing it. So if the Jacobian change little over the part of the domain of the ODE where the solution segment lives, then one Jacobian evaluation can be sufficient.

Note also that there can be 3,6,9 or 12 or even higher multiples of 3 as number of function evaluations for a single Radau5 step.

Comment: The solver may believe its sufficient, but the results are highly divergent. Is there a way to force it to evaluate the Jacobian at least once per step?

Comment: You can set the error tolerances more tightly. You can most of all set the absolute tolerance as a vector that is proportional the the vector of scales of the components. A mismatch of scales while the components are used as equal in the error estimate and step size control sometimes leads to erratic behavior of the minor components.